# VSCode Code Folding

Tags: text-editor, visual-studio-code

I am trying to install or update a setting that allows me to minimize and maximize code blocks within VS Code.  Similar to below and/or like Visual Studio:

https://www.flickr.com/photos/50988329@N02/25504022561/in/dateposted-public/

Just in case the image link doesn't work, I am speaking about the plus and minus signs/icons that you see next to the line numbers in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [February Update (0.10.10) for VSCode just added support for code folding](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/#_editor).

Try downloading that and giving it a try. You can enable or disable code folding with the `editor.folding` setting.

Comment: Thanks Matt.  You beat me to it on the post.  My VS Code updated a few hours after writing the post and noticed it automatically, as stated editor.folding setting.

Comment: And v1.17 added code folding by regions : https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_17#_editor